# Showing that intersection of cyclic groups is identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $|a|=10, |b|=21$. Show that $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=\{e\}$.

I think that $|a|=10$ implies there are subgroups of the cyclic group of order $2,5$; $|b|=21$ implies that there are subgroups of order $3,7$. How can I proceed to conclude that their intersection is identity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The intersection of subgroups is a subgroup. And according to Lagrange theorem the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.

Comment: The order of the intersection divides 10 and 21, so it divides the greatest common divisor, that is 1. Hence the intersection has order 1, thus it's the identity.

Comment: Probably here $|a|$ means the order of $a$. In general one uses the Bezout Identity, but here we can note that $21+(-2)(10)=1$.

Comment: @user279325 but {$3$} has order $1$ too, why ${e}$?

Comment: {3} is not a group and |3| $\ne$ 1.  The only group of order 1 is {e}.  The intersection of subgroups is a subgroup.  The intersection of cyclic subgroups is a cyclic subgroup.  If c is in both <a> and <b> then |c| divides 10 and |c| divides 21 so |c| = 1.  Thus c is such that $c^1 = e$.  $3^1 = 3 \ne e$.  So $c \ne 3$.  In fact $c^1 = c$ so $c = c^1 = e$ is the only member of the group.

Comment: Because $\{3\}$ is not a subgroup. Note that identity doesn't belong to it.

Comment: The "order" of an element is different than the "order" of a set.  The order of a set or group is the number of elements.  The order of a group element, a, is the smallest power, m, at which $a^m = e$.  The order of a group element always divides the order of the group set.  {3} is a set but it is not a group.  To make a group that has 3 in it, you need $<3> = \{e, 3, 3^2, ....\}$.  The order of 3 and the order of <3> is not 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) If A, B are subgroups of G then $A \cap B$ is a group with the group operator.

Proof: If a, b $\in A \cap B$ Then $a,b \in A$ and $a,b \in B$ then $ab \in A $and $ab \in B$ (because A and B are groups) so $ab \in A \cap B$.  So the group operator is closed in $A \cap B$.

Likewise $e \in A$ and $e \in B$ so $e \in A \cap B$.  And for all $a \in A \cap B$ $a^{-1}$ is in both A and B so $a^{-1} \in A \cap B$ so $A \cap B$ is a group.

2)  If $a$ is an element of a group with |a| = m (ie $a^m = e$) then the order of the element $b = a^k$ must divide m.

Proof: $b^m = (a^k)^m = (a^m)^k = e^k = e$.  Suppose |$b$| = $v$. And suppose $m = vj + i; 0<= i <v$.  Then $e = b^m = b^{vj + i} = (b^v)^jb^i = eb^i = b^i.$ But  $|b| = v > i$ so $i$ must be equal to $0$. So m = vj, v = |b| divides m.

3) Let |a| = 10, |b| = 21, the $\{e\} = <a> \cap <b>$.

$<a> \cap <b>$ is a group. Let $c \in <a> \cap <b>$. Then $c \in <a>$ and $c \in <b>$ so |c| divides |a| = 10 and |c| divides |b| = 21.  So |c| divides gcd(10, 21) = 1.  So |c| = 1.  So $c^1 = c = e$.  Thus $e$ is the only element of $<a> \cap <b>$.